# os.open doesn't create files with the given permission mode

Tags: python, linux, chmod, pathlib

When trying to open a file using os.open with the mode 777 (meaning allow everything) -

```
os.open("/tmp/lol", flags=(os.O_CREAT), mode=0o777)
```

It creates the file without the write permission like this -

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 cybellum cybellum       0 Nov 20 09:38 lol*
```

When trying to use chmod("/tmp/lol", 0o777), the file gains the right permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 cybellum cybellum       0 Nov 20 09:38 lol*
```

Why doesn't os.open work as expected?
And is there a way to create a file with the 777 mode (and if the file exists it will just change the permissions.. (Because I tried pathlib.Path.touch))?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a file with `open`, the permissions specified in the `open` call are modified by your `umask` setting.  The `umask` defines bits that are "masked out".  On my system, it looks like my current `umask` is `0002`:

```
$ umask
0002
```

This means that when I run code like yours:

```
import os
os.open('testfile', flags=(os.O_CREAT), mode=0o777)
```

I'll get the following behavior:

```
$ python filetest
$ ls -l testfile
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 lars lars       0 Nov 20 07:47 testfile
```

I can set the `umask` to different values to control the permissions
applied by default:

```
$ umask 022
$ python filetest
$ ls -l testfile
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 lars lars 0 Nov 20 07:49 testfile
```

Or:

```
$ umask 077
$ python filetest.py
$ ls -l testfile
-rwx------. 1 lars lars 0 Nov 20 07:50 testfile
```

Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

Comment: Note that [Python includes `os.umask`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.umask) for manipulating the `umask`.

Comment: Sure, although I would argue that in most cases you want to let the user manipulate their umask external to your code. If someone has explicitly set their umask to avoid creating world-readable documents, it can be surprising when something goes behind their back to make the change anyway.

Comment: Interesting! But what if you don't want to open all of the files using the set umask and use a specific file creation functionality that will be permissionless?

Comment: You can set `umask` to 0, of course, either external to your code or, as @ShadowRanger has suggested, using `os.umask`.

Comment: @larsks: Agreed that usually the user should be in charge of their `umask`, not the program.